# How to unpivot panel data?

Tags: pivot, unpivot, dolphindb

I have been working with panel data in a matrix format. Now, I want to convert the matrix into narrow data for certain analysis or processing tasks. Can the `unpivot` function be used to achieve this transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix cannot be directly converted to a narrow table. To achieve this transformation, you need to convert the matrix into a table before applying the `unpivot` function.

```
//panel data
n = 7
label = 2023.01.03 + 0..6
SH600000 = rand(4.0, n)//$DECIMAL64(3)
SH600004 = rand(14.0, n)//$DECIMAL64(3)
SH600006 = rand(114.0, n)//$DECIMAL64(3)
p = table(label, SH600000, SH600004, SH600006)
p = matrix(SH600000, SH600004, SH600006)
p.rename!(label, `SH600000`SH600004`SH600006)
t = table(p.rowNames() as label, p)
// unpivot
f = t.unpivot(`label, `SH600000`SH600006`SH600004, first)
select * from f order by label, valueType
```